# Inhertiance using generic type constraint

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

How can I properly inherit a class (of another class and interfaces) that have a generic type with a generic type constraint (where)?

```
class A { }
class B { }
interface I { }

class C<T> where T : A, B, I { }
```

In this example A, B and I is treated as base for T. Inhertiance of 2 classes is not possible in C#. 
But I want that A is Baseclass of the generic type T and B/I is baseclass/interface of C. How to do this?

As soon as I use the where-constraint for the generic type I cannot derive my class C anymore

Comment: Have you tried  C<T>:B,I Where T:A ?

Comment: `As soon as I use the where-constraint for the generic type I cannot derive my class C anymore` and what did you try in that regard?  Did you have a compiler error when trying to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class A
    {
    }
   public class B
   {
   }

   public interface I
   {
   }

   public class C<T> : B, I where T : A
   {
   }
```